# How can I verify logical equivalence without using Truth Table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have an assignment and I need to prove the following logical equivalence using Laws of Logic and not using Truth Table:

p → q ≡ ~q → ~p

LAWS OF LOGIC:

1.Commutative Law: p ↔ q ≡ q ↔ p

2.Implication Laws: p →q ≡ ~p ∨ q
≡ ~(p ∧ ~q)

3.Exportation Law: (p ∧ q)→r ≡ p →(q →r)

4.Equivalence: p ↔ q ≡ (p →q)∧(q →p)

5.Reductio ad absurdum p →q ≡ (p ∧ ~q) →c

Kindly help me solving it, need to present it in 24 hours. Thanks all

Comment: This wiki may help:https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rule_of_Transposition/Formulation_1

Comment: Use Implication law: $p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q$ and $\lnot q \to \lnot p \equiv \lnot \lnot q \lor \lnot p$.

Comment: If we use Implication Law the we will get
p → q ≡ ¬p ∨ q

and

¬q → ¬p ≡ ¬¬q ∨ ¬p

Using Double Negation we get

¬q → ¬p ≡ q ∨ ¬p

so would it be equal to the answer of L.H.S?